# Regex to match a string which does NOT have some words before @ symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to discard a string if some words are present before the character @ in it.

**Example:**
I want words `foo` and `bar` that should **NOT** be present on a string before @ symbol but the same words are allowed after @ symbol.

**I do NOT want these:**

*abc`foo`xyz@domain.com*

*`bar`abc@domain.com*

*`bar`abc@domain`foo`.com*

**I want these:**

*abcxyz@domain`foo`.com*

*pqrabc@domain`bar`.com*

*pqrabc@domain.com*

---

I have regex `^((?!(foo|bar)).)*$`, but it also discards strings that have `foo` and `bar` after @ symbol even if the words are NOt present before @.

I only want it to discard if `foo` or `bar` is present before @ symbol in a string.

---

Do you have an idea how can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to match a string if the words are before or after? Your examples show that you want to match if the words are after @ and at the end you say that you want to match if they are before @.

Comment: I just updated the question.  Match strings which does NOT have the words before @ symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assert at each character position preceding the `@` that it is not the start of `foo` or `bar`:

```
^((?!foo|bar).)+@.*$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9R88vJ/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
^(?!.*(?:foo|bar).*@).*?@.*$
```

**Explanation:**
A simple and single negative look ahead to make sure that foo  or bar doesn't exist before @. Since it is  a single look ahead so it operates faster.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0QoYiD/1)

Sample Source:

```js
const regex = /^(?!.*(?:foo|bar).*@).*?@.*$/gm;

const str = `I do NOT want these:
abcfooxyz@domain.com
barabc@domain.com
barabc@domainfoo.com
I want these:
abcxyz@domainfoo.com
pqrabc@domainbar.com
pqrabc@domain.com`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`${match}`);
    });
}
```